# Can't delete row from SQLite database in iOS?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, sqlite

I am using this code to delete row from Sqlite3 Database,but it's not working,insert,update,select query are working fine, but the delete statement is not working in my code

```
 -(void)delete{

        str=title.text;
        sqlite3_stmt *selectstmt;
        if (sqlite3_open([path UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"delete from ToDo where title=\"%@\"",str];
            NSLog(@"%@",deleteSQL);
            const char *sql = [deleteSQL UTF8String];
            sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL); 
            if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &selectstmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
               NSLog(@"success");
            else
              NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));            
            }
            sqlite3_finalize(selectstmt);
            sqlite3_close(database);
        }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should really post what actually happens (e.g., do you see an error, if so, which error? does it crash? does it return OK but do nothing? etc.) or we can't help you. Also, just skimming this, you've prepared your statement twice (which I believe is an error, but I'm not sure) and you've never executed it. Not executing it would be my first guess as to why it's... well... not executing?

Comment: I think you missing this statement  `sqlite3_step(selectstmt);` and also the bind statement is missing too :)

Comment: Also, don't even attempt to delete from a database located in your app bundle - files there are not writable.

Comment: I have posted answer, take a look at it. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can delete particular recored from sqlite database using below code:-

```
NSDictionary *d =(NSDictionary *) [YourMutableArray objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [path objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dbPath =[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"db.sqlite"];
sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database);

if(deleteStmt == nil) 
{

    NSString *deleteStatementNS = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                                   @"delete from tbl_postoffice where type = '%@'",
                                   urusniqIDentifire];
    const char *sql = [deleteStatementNS UTF8String];

    //const char *sql ="delete from tbl_todo where type = yourDbfildeRecored";
    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &deleteStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating delete statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}

//When binding parameters, index starts from 1 and not zero.
sqlite3_bind_text(deleteStmt, 1, [[d valueForKey:@"type"] UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(deleteStmt)) 
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error while deleting. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

sqlite3_reset(deleteStmt);
```

hope its Helps for you

Answer (score 3):

Hi take a look at it.

I thing you are doing wrong in passing the parameter.

**EDIT:**

```
    str=title.text;
    [self openDatabase];//Logic to open database goes here
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt=nil;
    BOOL status=FALSE;

    NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"delete from ToDo where title='%@'",str];
    NSLog(@"%@",deleteSQL);
    const char *sql = [deleteSQL UTF8String];


   //const char *sql ="delete from ToDo where title='%@'";

   if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &stmt, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
   {
         sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, [_testId UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_STATIC);

         if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(stmt))
               { 
                 NSLog(@"Error while Deleting");
               }


    }
    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);
  [self closeDatabase];//Logic to close database goes here
```

Comment: It's usually considered bad practice to not use the labels for checking results. Seeing `dbRetCount==101` makes it hard for people to understand what the code is doing. Are you checking that it deleted 101 items? Is 101 the magic "I deleted it!" number? etc. You should compare with `SQLITE_DONE` so it's clear what you're checking against.

Comment: @JasonCoco I dont want to sound rude, but i m not checking that **it deleted 101 items** , If you take a look at this site you may come to know that 101 is integer value used for #define SQLITE_DONE. **http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html**

Comment: I know exactly what it is. I know that *you* know you're not checking to see if you've deleted 101 items. However, anyone else reading this code may have no idea why they're comparing the result to 101. You should use the `SQLITE_DONE` tag, not the raw return value to make it clear.

Comment: Also, I should point out as well that you've named your variable `dbRetCount` which is extremely misleading... so you've actually *suggested* that you're comparing some count (in this case, it'd have to be the number of deleted rows) with the value 101. This is a Q&A site for people of all different skill levels, and this example is extremely misleading. If you edit to clarify, I'll remove -1

Comment: NSString *deleteSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"delete from ToDo where title='%@'",str];
Awesome line.

Answer (score 0):

Yes @jason Coco is correct you have prepared your statement twice and you have not called step also after prepare statement..try calling this after prepare:

```
if (sqlite3_step(selectstmt) == SQLITE_DONE)
{
    NSLog(@"success");
}
```